# How to get all populated ranges in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to find all populated ranges in an Excel sheet. For example, for the sheet in the picture I want to get two ranges:

```
Range1 := B2:C4    
Range2 := E4:F6
```

[image: Excel sheet]
Is there an "intelligent" way to do so?

Comment: All populated rectangular ranges?  What result would you expect if there was a value in D4?  3 ranges?

Comment: But not D4:F4 ?  That should also be included I would think...  Or B4:F4?  You will need to outline some quite specific rules here I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams, My bad - the third one should be B4:F4

Comment: `Sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas`

Comment: @jbarker - for the example with a value in D4 that gives: B2:C3, B4:D4, E4:F6

Comment: A bit tricky to do if you really want to get all possible rectangular ranges, including any overlapping ones.  What's this for?

Comment: @TimWilliams - I'm trying to find a way to automatically detect all areas that can be transformed to tables for analysis purpose

Comment: @jbarker2160 - I think your answer gives me a good place to start. Thanks